# Rails update object without supplying fields with validates presence: true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I'm trying to update a user object through a form. However, I don't want to allow usernames to be changed. I don't have the field present on the form. When I submit the form, it gives me an error that I cannot leave the username confirmation blank. Here's my controller:

```
def update
    @partner = CommunityPartner.find(params[:id])
    if @partner.update_attributes(allowed_update_params)

    else
        render('edit')
    end
end

def allowed_create_params
        params.require(:community_partner).permit(:name, :username, :display_email,
                                                                                            :username_confirmation,
                                                                                            :contact_method, :password, 
                                                                                            :password_confirmation,
                                                                                            :phone_number, :address,
                                                                                            :description, :tags_string)
    end

def allowed_update_params
        params.permit!(:name) if params[:name]
        params.permit!(:display_email) if params[:display_email]
        params.permit!(:contact_method) if params[:contact_method]
        params.permit!(:phone_number) if params[:phone_number]
        params.permit!(:address) if params[:address]
        params.permit!(:description) if params[:description]
        params.permit!(:tags_string) if params[:tags_string]
    end
```

How can I update only the params I'm allowing in the update action without touching the others?

EDIT: validation methods

```
validates(:name, presence: { on: :create })
validates(:username, presence: { on: :create }, confirmation: { on: :create }, uniqueness: true)
validates(:contact_method, presence: { on: :create })
validates(:username_confirmation, presence: { on: :create })
validates(:display_email, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL })
validates(:address, presence: { on: :create })
validates(:phone_number, presence: { on: :create })
validates(:description, presence: { on: :create })
```

Comment: please show your validation methods

Comment: You can also as on: :create to the confirmation validation to only ensure it is there when the object is initially created.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have a validation on `username_confirmation` in the `CommunityPartner` model.

Use `on: :create` option on that validation. So, that validation would only be checked at the time of `CommunityPartner` record creation and `not while updating`(where you don't pass `username_confirmation`).

For example:

```
class CommunityPartner < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :username_confirmation, presence: true, on: :create
end
```

Comment: @Hugo I see the EDIT you made to the question with validations. Are you still getting the error?

Comment: Sorry for some reason your comments aren't showing up in my inbox. The issue hasn't been resolved because the updates still won't save, but I'm not getting any errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can skip validation using `update_all` helper instead of `update_attributes`.